# Is there a way to create TEXT watermark in pure javascript?

Tags: javascript

I would like to create and add textual watermark to a webpage. It should be created in pure javascript.

**EDIT:**

**Explanation:** Take current page as an example and I wish I could display semi-transparent text "STACKOVERFLOW" in the middle of this page.

Comment: Is this what you need??? [link](http://www.davidjrush.com/blog/2011/01/javascript-creating-a-simple-textbox-watermark-with-text/)

Comment: Yes. What have you tried, where are you stuck? Help us help you. But, I am confident that it possible to create and add a textual watermark to a webpage in pure javascript.

Comment: You'll have to define what you mean by a watermark.  The link @C-linkNepal posted is better accomplished, in today's web, by the `placeholder` attribute.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I have not tried anything yet. just trying to figure it out

Comment: The first questions I've got to ask: Why pure javascript? Why not some CSS at least? For exmple use some javascript to insert an element on a page, with a class or id and use CSS to style that appropriately

Comment: @JonP I'll ultimately switch to this option if I failed to do it pure javascript

Comment: @C-linkNepal ... it's a placeholder not a watermark indeed

Comment: I doubt if the OP meant no CSS, more likely he meant no jQuery.

Comment: CSS Hybrid if you decide to go that way (not too diferent ftom @JonDinham answer) http://jsfiddle.net/gsxzxfhm/

Comment: Also, is this for HTML like jondinham's answer provided (which can be removed via any developer tools), or on top of an image and rendered server-side?

Answer (score 2):

Making a watermark with pure JS is long, but easier with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var Html = "<div id='myDiv'>My Watermark</div>";
  $("body").append(Html);

  $("#myDiv").css({
    "color":"#bbb","font-size":"100px",
    "position":"absolute","top":"0px","left":"0px",
    "z-index":"-1","transform":"rotate(45deg)"
  });
});
```

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jondinham/agz5tytb/

With pure JavaScript, it's harder because the 'transform' css is not a standard in old browsers. Anyway, it can be done this way:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(div);

div.innerHTML = "My Watermark";
div.style.color = "#bbb";
div.style.fontSize = "100px";
div.style.position = "absolute";
div.style.top = "0px";
div.style.left = "0px";
div.style.zIndex = "-1";

div.style.transform = "rotate(45deg)"; //standard
div.style.msTransform = "rotate(45deg)"; //IE
div.style.mozTransform = "rotate(45deg)"; //Firefox
div.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(45deg)"; //Chrome
div.style.oTransform = "rotate(45deg)"; //Opera
```

See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jondinham/7fqg9n6w/

Comment: Not any harder to do with HTML and CSS -- you aren't doing anything special there.

Comment: That's perfect but my requirement is pure javascript.

Comment: I think Jquery is not doing anything special here. It's CSS. I'll try to use this CSS in pure javascript.

Comment: Bubba, i've added the pure JS solution, mark it as answer, tks

Answer (score -3):

https://codepen.io/emrahaydemir/pen/OJZYwYz

```js
async function addWatermarkToImage(file) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const image = await fileToDataURL(file);
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    const fontSize =
      (canvas.width + canvas.height) / ctx.measureText(text).width;
    ctx.font = fontSize + "px verdana";
    const textSize = ctx.measureText(text);
    ctx.globalAlpha = watermarkOpacity;
    ctx.fillStyle = waterMarkColor;
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    let startY = -canvas.height / 2;
    let startX = -canvas.width / 2;
    const xGap = canvas.width * 0.07;
    const yGap = canvas.height * 0.07;
    for (let index = 0; startX < canvas.width; index++) {
      for (let yIndex = 0; startY < canvas.height; index++) {
        ctx.strokeText(text, startX, startY);
        startY += fontSize + yGap;
      }
      startY = 0;
      startX += textSize.width + xGap;
    }
    resolve(canvas.toDataURL());
  });
}
```